# Add points (proximity) ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, 3d-analyst, proximity, viewshed

I have a punctual shapefile of wind turbines. The task is to discover if those wind turbines are visible to the human eye. The human eye can see a maximum of 1.6 meters. Which tool can create or add new points near to the wind turbines in a radius of 5 km and then apply the viewshed analysis.

Comment: This [ArcPro tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f96ede37dcd04c2e96dc903a4ce26244) appears to be able to create points at a specified radius? Then use the standard viewshed tool.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused in viewshed analysis.  The human eye can see a lot further than 1.6m - it sounds like you mean that is your observer height.  Can you clarify what these points are which you wish to add - any digitizing tool can do that.  Alternatively are you asking how to do viewshed analysis (in which case you only need the turbine points and the height of the turbines)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: What is a "punctual shapefile"?  Is it perhaps a point shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless the fact that human eye can see farther than 1.6 meters, to create points in a radius of 5km from your turbines you could:

1. calculate a buffer around your wind turbines with the [Buffer tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm), specifying your turbines as input and 5km as your distance
2. if you have a Spatial or 3D Analyst extension (which you should otherwise you could not make a visibility analysis with ArcGIS) OR if you have an advanced license, use the [Create Random Points tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm) to create some points within 5 km from your turbines. here you would use the buffer you cerated in step 1 as your constraining feature.